# Use AWS RDS Postgres Replicas as a single cluster with 1 endpoint

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

RDS Postgres Replicas can scale up to 5 replicas. But when I create a replica, it creates it as a single instance, not as a cluster.

If I want to use RDS Postgres Read Replica clusters so that my single application can  handle high TPS and the TPS can be shared by multiple RDS Replicas.

In know this is possible with Aurora replicas, as Aurora creates a cluster of replicas which has single endpoint and which can scale in or scale out. But All normal RDS
Postgres Replicas are created like single instances with different endpoints.

Is it possible to make RDS postgres replicas as a cluster with 1 endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clusters are for `Aurora`, not for `RDS`. So you have to make sure you **choose** `Aurora` when you try to create your Database in AWS Console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Marin is correct.

RDS does not provide auto load balancing between running reader instances.
You have to manage load balancing between replica instances yourself.

In Aurora, there is auto load balancing as well as auto scaling amongst different reader instances.